Error: type String is not a subtype of type Map String, dynamic
Get an Error: type String is not a subtype of type Map String, dynamic
import 'package:ajooyo/features/products/models/product_model.dart';

class CartItem {
  final Product product;
  final int quantity;
  final String id;

  CartItem({
    required this.product,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.id,
  });

  factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CartItem(
      product: Product.fromJson(json['product']),
      quantity: json['quantity'],
      id: json['_id'],
    );
  }
}

Cart model

import 'package:ajooyo/features/products/models/product_cart_item_model.dart';

class Cart {
  final String id;
  final String userId;
  final List<CartItem> items;

  Cart({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.items,
  });

  factory Cart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Cart(
      id: json['_id'] as String,
      userId: json['user'] as String,
      items: (json['items'] as List)
          .map((item) => CartItem.fromJson(item as Map<String, 
           dynamic>)).toList(),
    );
  }
}



Here is the json file coming from the backend
{
    "updatedCart": {
        "_id": "66442f4",
        "user": "6628996ba",
        "items": [
            {
                "product": {
                    "_id": "66496e7e",
                    "user": "6696ba",
                    "vendor": "66311944",
                    "productName": "Yemlays Men's Fashion Comfortable Hoodie-black",
                    "productBrandName": "Yemlays",
                    "productPrice": "24,360",
                    "productDescription": "Welcome to our shop.",
                    "productDaysOfDelivery": "3",
                    "productType": "Clothing",
                    "productSize": "Regular",
                    "productQuantity": "",
                    "productImages": [
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://_image/td3tadqj2n52vpelxntk.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c8b824675c8aaa196e7f"
                        }
                    ],
                    "productAvailability": true,
                    "productStatus": "active",
                    "createdAt": "2024-05-12T13:48:40.612Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2024-05-12T13:48:40.612Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "quantity": 2,
                "_id": "664454addc21f61eb83252f7"
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "_id": "66403",
                    "user": "66ba",
                    "vendor": "66310e944",
                    "productName": "Yemlays Martin Boots Men's Tooling All-match High-top Shoes-beige",
                    "productBrandName": "Yemlays",
                    "productPrice": "9,467",
                    "productDescription": "This pair in addition to.",
                    "productDaysOfDelivery": "3",
                    "productType": "Foot Wares",
                    "productSize": "44",
                    "productQuantity": "",
                    "productImages": [
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://t_image/xalew0pxva25ly49xb1w.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e74"
                        },
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://r9w.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e75"
                        },
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://re.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e76"
                        },
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://repg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e77"
                        }
                    ],
                    "productAvailability": true,
                    "productStatus": "active",
                    "createdAt": "2024-05-12T13:47:14.889Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2024-05-12T13:47:14.889Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "_id": "664455b9dc21f61eb8325313"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 1
    }
}

I expect it to map through the data, but i keep on getting the data fromJson
But in the below code it printed Response data is a Map; which mean the api data is a Map data,
Also for this print("Response type: ${response.data.runtimeType}");, it printed Response type: _Map<String, dynamic>
So i seriously don't know where the error is coming from...
Future<Cart?> addProductToCart(String productId, int quantity) async {
    try {
      const endpoint = "user/add_product_cart";
      final response = await apiProvider.post(endpoint, data: {
        'productId': productId,
        'quantity': quantity,
      });

      // Debugging information
      print("Response type: ${response.data.runtimeType}");
      print("Response data: ${response.data}");

      if (response.data is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        print("Response data is a Map");

        final updatedCartData =
            response.data['updatedCart'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        print("updatedCart data type: ${updatedCartData.runtimeType}");

        return Cart.fromJson(updatedCartData);
      } else {
        print("Response data is not a Map");
        throw Exception('Unexpected response format');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      print('Error occures here');
      rethrow;
      // throw Exception('Failed to add product to cart: $e');
    }
  }


provide Cart model also.

Cart model added


I expect it to map through the data, but i keep on getting the data
fromJson But in the below code it printed Response data is a Map;
which mean the api data is a Map data...

Correct, the whole response is a map.
However, the error of type String is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> can be unrelated to the main response, it can be one of the sub-types of the main response, such as the Product or any sub-type of it. Somewhere, an object (map) in the response is getting deserialized as a string instead.
A good way to resolve such an issue is to make a new model (sub-type) for each object in your response:
class ResponseModel {
  UpdatedCart? updatedCart;

  ResponseModel({this.updatedCart});

  ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    updatedCart = json['updatedCart'] != null
        ? UpdatedCart.fromJson(json['updatedCart'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (updatedCart != null) {
      data['updatedCart'] = updatedCart!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class UpdatedCart {
  String? sId;
  String? user;
  List<Items>? items;
  int? iV;

  UpdatedCart({this.sId, this.user, this.items, this.iV});

  UpdatedCart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    user = json['user'];
    if (json['items'] != null) {
      items = <Items>[];
      json['items'].forEach((v) {
        items!.add(Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['_id'] = sId;
    data['user'] = user;
    if (items != null) {
      data['items'] = items!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['__v'] = iV;
    return data;
  }
}

class Items {
  Product? product;
  int? quantity;
  String? sId;

  Items({this.product, this.quantity, this.sId});

  Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    product =
        json['product'] != null ? Product.fromJson(json['product']) : null;
    quantity = json['quantity'];
    sId = json['_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (product != null) {
      data['product'] = product!.toJson();
    }
    data['quantity'] = quantity;
    data['_id'] = sId;
    return data;
  }
}

class Product {
  String? sId;
  String? user;
  String? vendor;
  String? productName;
  String? productBrandName;
  String? productPrice;
  String? productDescription;
  String? productDaysOfDelivery;
  String? productType;
  String? productSize;
  String? productQuantity;
  List<ProductImages>? productImages;
  bool? productAvailability;
  String? productStatus;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  int? iV;

  Product(
      {this.sId,
      this.user,
      this.vendor,
      this.productName,
      this.productBrandName,
      this.productPrice,
      this.productDescription,
      this.productDaysOfDelivery,
      this.productType,
      this.productSize,
      this.productQuantity,
      this.productImages,
      this.productAvailability,
      this.productStatus,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.iV});

  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    user = json['user'];
    vendor = json['vendor'];
    productName = json['productName'];
    productBrandName = json['productBrandName'];
    productPrice = json['productPrice'];
    productDescription = json['productDescription'];
    productDaysOfDelivery = json['productDaysOfDelivery'];
    productType = json['productType'];
    productSize = json['productSize'];
    productQuantity = json['productQuantity'];
    if (json['productImages'] != null) {
      productImages = <ProductImages>[];
      json['productImages'].forEach((v) {
        productImages!.add(ProductImages.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    productAvailability = json['productAvailability'];
    productStatus = json['productStatus'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['_id'] = sId;
    data['user'] = user;
    data['vendor'] = vendor;
    data['productName'] = productName;
    data['productBrandName'] = productBrandName;
    data['productPrice'] = productPrice;
    data['productDescription'] = productDescription;
    data['productDaysOfDelivery'] = productDaysOfDelivery;
    data['productType'] = productType;
    data['productSize'] = productSize;
    data['productQuantity'] = productQuantity;
    if (productImages != null) {
      data['productImages'] =
          productImages!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['productAvailability'] = productAvailability;
    data['productStatus'] = productStatus;
    data['createdAt'] = createdAt;
    data['updatedAt'] = updatedAt;
    data['__v'] = iV;
    return data;
  }
}

class ProductImages {
  String? productUrl;
  String? sId;

  ProductImages({this.productUrl, this.sId});

  ProductImages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productUrl = json['productUrl'];
    sId = json['_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['productUrl'] = productUrl;
    data['_id'] = sId;
    return data;
  }
}

ResponseModel is the output of parsing the whole response, which contains sub-types for each object in the response. For instance, you could access data as:
final response = ResponseModel.fromJson(responseMap);

final items = response.updatedCart?.items;
final productBrandName = items?.first.product?.productBrandName;

responseMap is simply your response. You could test it by declaring a local (mock) one instead of doing an actual endpoint request:
const responseMap = {
    "updatedCart": {
        "_id": "66442f4",
        "user": "6628996ba",
        "items": [
            {
                "product": {
                    "_id": "66496e7e",
                    "user": "6696ba",
                    "vendor": "66311944",
                    "productName": "Yemlays Men's Fashion Comfortable Hoodie-black",
                    "productBrandName": "Yemlays",
                    "productPrice": "24,360",
                    "productDescription": "Welcome to our shop.",
                    "productDaysOfDelivery": "3",
                    "productType": "Clothing",
                    "productSize": "Regular",
                    "productQuantity": "",
                    "productImages": [
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://_image/td3tadqj2n52vpelxntk.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c8b824675c8aaa196e7f"
                        }
                    ],
                    "productAvailability": true,
                    "productStatus": "active",
                    "createdAt": "2024-05-12T13:48:40.612Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2024-05-12T13:48:40.612Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "quantity": 2,
                "_id": "664454addc21f61eb83252f7"
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "_id": "66403",
                    "user": "66ba",
                    "vendor": "66310e944",
                    "productName": "Yemlays Martin Boots Men's Tooling All-match High-top Shoes-beige",
                    "productBrandName": "Yemlays",
                    "productPrice": "9,467",
                    "productDescription": "This pair in addition to.",
                    "productDaysOfDelivery": "3",
                    "productType": "Foot Wares",
                    "productSize": "44",
                    "productQuantity": "",
                    "productImages": [
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://t_image/xalew0pxva25ly49xb1w.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e74"
                        },
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://r9w.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e75"
                        },
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://re.jpg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e76"
                        },
                        {
                            "productUrl": "https://repg",
                            "_id": "6640c86224675c8aaa196e77"
                        }
                    ],
                    "productAvailability": true,
                    "productStatus": "active",
                    "createdAt": "2024-05-12T13:47:14.889Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2024-05-12T13:47:14.889Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "_id": "664455b9dc21f61eb8325313"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 1
    }
};


Thank you all for the contribution.
After carefully reviewing all the model mostly Product Model, according to some suggestion I found out that inside the Product the User and Vendor Model, somethings comes as map and something comes as String, so I needed to check for both right inside the Product Model.
if (json['user'] is Map) {
  user = User.fromJson(json['user']);
} else if (json['user'] is String) {
  user = User(id: json['user'], email: '', userName: '');
}
if (json['vendor'] is Map) {
  vendor = Vendor.fromJson(json['vendor']);
} else if (json['vendor'] is String) {
  vendor = Vendor(id: json['vendor'], vBusinessName: '');
}

And that solves the error

I suppose your model is not fitting json data. You can convert your json data to class simply with this website: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/
I convert your json data to model and result like this:
class CartItem {
  UpdatedCart? updatedCart;

  CartItem({this.updatedCart});

  CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    updatedCart = json['updatedCart'] != null
        ? UpdatedCart.fromJson(json['updatedCart'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (updatedCart != null) {
      data['updatedCart'] = updatedCart!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class UpdatedCart {
  String? sId;
  String? user;
  List<Items>? items;
  int? iV;

  UpdatedCart({this.sId, this.user, this.items, this.iV});

  UpdatedCart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    user = json['user'];
    if (json['items'] != null) {
      items = <Items>[];
      json['items'].forEach((v) {
        items!.add(Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['_id'] = sId;
    data['user'] = user;
    if (items != null) {
      data['items'] = items!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['__v'] = iV;
    return data;
  }
}

class Items {
  Product? product;
  int? quantity;
  String? sId;

  Items({this.product, this.quantity, this.sId});

  Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    product =
        json['product'] != null ? Product.fromJson(json['product']) : null;
    quantity = json['quantity'];
    sId = json['_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (product != null) {
      data['product'] = product!.toJson();
    }
    data['quantity'] = quantity;
    data['_id'] = sId;
    return data;
  }
}

class Product {
  String? sId;
  String? user;
  String? vendor;
  String? productName;
  String? productBrandName;
  String? productPrice;
  String? productDescription;
  String? productDaysOfDelivery;
  String? productType;
  String? productSize;
  String? productQuantity;
  List<ProductImages>? productImages;
  bool? productAvailability;
  String? productStatus;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  int? iV;

  Product(
      {this.sId,
      this.user,
      this.vendor,
      this.productName,
      this.productBrandName,
      this.productPrice,
      this.productDescription,
      this.productDaysOfDelivery,
      this.productType,
      this.productSize,
      this.productQuantity,
      this.productImages,
      this.productAvailability,
      this.productStatus,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.iV});

  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    user = json['user'];
    vendor = json['vendor'];
    productName = json['productName'];
    productBrandName = json['productBrandName'];
    productPrice = json['productPrice'];
    productDescription = json['productDescription'];
    productDaysOfDelivery = json['productDaysOfDelivery'];
    productType = json['productType'];
    productSize = json['productSize'];
    productQuantity = json['productQuantity'];
    if (json['productImages'] != null) {
      productImages = <ProductImages>[];
      json['productImages'].forEach((v) {
        productImages!.add(ProductImages.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    productAvailability = json['productAvailability'];
    productStatus = json['productStatus'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['_id'] = sId;
    data['user'] = user;
    data['vendor'] = vendor;
    data['productName'] = productName;
    data['productBrandName'] = productBrandName;
    data['productPrice'] = productPrice;
    data['productDescription'] = productDescription;
    data['productDaysOfDelivery'] = productDaysOfDelivery;
    data['productType'] = productType;
    data['productSize'] = productSize;
    data['productQuantity'] = productQuantity;
    if (productImages != null) {
      data['productImages'] = productImages!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['productAvailability'] = productAvailability;
    data['productStatus'] = productStatus;
    data['createdAt'] = createdAt;
    data['updatedAt'] = updatedAt;
    data['__v'] = iV;
    return data;
  }
}

class ProductImages {
  String? productUrl;
  String? sId;

  ProductImages({this.productUrl, this.sId});

  ProductImages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productUrl = json['productUrl'];
    sId = json['_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['productUrl'] = productUrl;
    data['_id'] = sId;
    return data;
  }
}


